# having trouble passing env var to mongodb driver

Tags: mongodb, go

hello everyone :) noob here

how come i get this error message from the mongodb driver's `Connect()` function

i have this code:

```golang
        // this Println() works fine
    fmt.Println(os.Getenv(MONGO_URI_ENV_VAR))

    client, err := mongo.Connect(  // this is where it's erroring out 
        context.TODO(),
        options.Client().ApplyURI(os.Getenv(MONGO_URI_ENV_VAR)),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("mongo.Connect(): %s\n", err)
    }
```

and i get the printline of the api key from the env var fine
but the `mongo.Connect()` function errors out saying:

```
2023/07/22 21:47:25 mongo.Connect(): error parsing uri: scheme must be "mongodb" or "mongodb+srv"
```

the url looks something like this btw:

```
"mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<project-name>.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

additional info:
when i pass just a regular string instead of getting value of the envar and passing that into the `ApplyURI()` method, it works. but i'd rather not commit that to the repo nomsayin

Answer (score 0):

figured it out,
i was passing single quotes to env var through the shell, I thought that's you're supposed to do it coz the shell would parse the reserved characters like this:

```
MONGO_URI='mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<project-name>.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

but apparently the single quotes shouldn't be there?

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the env load function in the main.go file and also add the mongoDB function in main.go it will work.

```
err := godotenv.Load(".env")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
}
mongoDbClient := configs.NewNoSqlDB()
```